# GAE email quota increase timing and Google contact?

Tags: gae-quotas

Submitted a request to increase email quota several weeks ago, have not heard anything and every time I click the link it says it's under review. I read other threads and it seems like one week is the normal response. I have tried navigating Google's customer service contacts but I could not find anything that seemed to apply for contacting anyone.

FWIW it's a paid app through Google Wallet that anytime an email is sent it is a few pennies in Google's pockets, which is basically what I want to explain to whomever is in charge of approving an increase. It is not under a paid account, although it is a billing-enabled account that every once in awhile Google gets a few more pennies for usage quotas being exceeded.

Anybody have a contact number or advice?